# moment.js, list days based on locale dow

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a script that is setting the day to start the week in the locale, however when I list out the days they arent in order that I expect:

```
moment.updateLocale(this.language, {
    week: {
        dow: 4,
    },
});
```

```
const weekDays = moment.weekdaysMin();
```

In this scenario I would expect to get the list:

```
Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed
```

But I always get:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
```

I would really appreciate some assistance as I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass boolean argument to `weekdaysMin` to get weekdays sorted by locale.

See [Listing the months and weekdays of the current Moment.js locale](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) section of the docs:

> Similarly, `moment.monthsShort` returns abbreviated month names, and `moment.weekdays`, `moment.weekdaysShort`, `moment.weekdaysMin` return lists of weekdays.
> ...
> As of **2.13.0** you can pass a bool as the first parameter of the weekday functions. If true, the weekdays will be returned in locale specific order.

Here a live sample:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: {
    dow: 4,
  },
});
const weekDays = moment.weekdaysMin();
console.log(weekDays);
const weekDaysSort = moment.weekdaysMin(true);
console.log(weekDaysSort);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok yea that works, I did have it set to true originally but removed it to see if that would resolve the issue. turns out that it wasn't updating the dow correctly in the locale.